# How do I test in C# if an exe is running correctly?

Tags: c#

I have a `viewer.exe` that loads at startup some models (`*.mdl`) from a "models" folder. Some of the models crash `viewer.exe`: "viewer.exe has stopped working. Windows can check online for a solution to the problem".
What I could do is move all the `.mdl` files in a "source" folder and then manually test for each `.mdl` file moved to "models" if `viewer.exe` is running but, there are a lot of files to check.  How do I move each `*.mdl` file from "source" to "models" and test programmatically if `viewer.exe` is running correctly?

Here is the code I use for my first problem: to move the `.mdl files` from "source" folder sub-directories in "models". Some of the files had identical names but different size:

```
String mask = "*.mdl";
String source = @"c:\Source\";
String destination = @"c:\Models\";

String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(source, mask, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (String file in files)
{
    if (File.Exists(file) && !File.Exists(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name))
    {
        File.Move(file, destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
    }
    else
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
        long s = f.Length;
        FileInfo f2 = new FileInfo(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
        long s2 = f2.Length;
        if (s >= s2)
        {
            File.Delete(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
            File.Move(file, destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use process.start(startInfo) (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)

Wait a few seconds, check if the process has terminated, then the returned process.hasexited (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx)

then kill it anyway using process.kill() (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)

You might need to turn off windows error reporting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx

Comment: This is accurate to answer the question, but @Olivier's answer is a much better way of solving the problem which is actually being experienced.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't agree, The title of the question is how to test if the exe is running correctly, and he does explicitly say in the question "and test programmatically if viewer.exe is running correctly?" how does @Olivier's answer address this point?

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I need but there is one problem: I tried using Process.Start(@"C\Viewer\viewer.exe") and it starts "isolated", it doesn't load the .mdl files, even though the models folder is in the same directory as the application. If I normally start the application by double clicking, it works.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx for how to start a process and pass in a parameter (in your case, the name of the file) should do it!

Comment: Just found out that if I use Process.Start("viewer.exe") and then place mycompiledapp.exe in the same directory as viewer.exe, everything works as it should with no need for specifying arguments. Again, thanks a lot, this is definitely what I was looking for.

Comment: Thats great Tony, in that case, can I get an upvote/ accepted answer please?

Comment: I want to give you an upvote/ accepted answer, you gave me real useful information, but I don't know how. It 's my first time posting here.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation for upvote. Your answer is accepted.

Comment: @ImmortalBlue - Upon another read, I can see where I misread it the first time.  I interpreted `viewer.exe` as the OP's program, in which case the OP simply needed to catch the exceoption.  Now I see that it's an external program.

Comment: @Bobson, no worries, I think I had the luck that I'd previously hit the same problem he has. I think he's playing around with some DirectX models, in the DirectX model viewer, and a whole load of them don't work right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Surround the operations which can fail in try-catch statements

```
try {
    File.Delete(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // File could not be deleted
}
try {
    File.Move(file, destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // File could not be moved
}
```

In the catch statement do whatever you want to do in case the files could not be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled windows error reporting and this is how the program looks like now:

```
        String mask = "*.mdl";
        String source = @"c:\source\";
        String destination = @"C:\Viewer\Models\";
        String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(source, mask, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

       foreach (String file in files)
       {
           if (File.Exists(file) && !File.Exists(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name))
           {
               File.Move(file, destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
           }
           else
           {
               FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
               long s = f.Length;
               FileInfo f2 = new FileInfo(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
               long s2 = f2.Length;
               if (s >= s2)
               {
                   File.Delete(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
                   File.Move(file, destination + new FileInfo(file).Name);
               }
           }

    //mycompiledapp.exe is placed in Viewer folder for this to work
        Process myprocess = Process.Start(@"viewer.exe"); 
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        if (myprocess.HasExited) //Process crashes, exiting automatically
        {
    //Deletes the file that makes the viewer.exe crash
            File.Delete(destination + new FileInfo(file).Name); 
        }
        else
        {
            myprocess.Kill();
        }
       }
```